# Connect remotely to Win7 from outside local network

Tags: windows-7, remote-access, remmina

I have Ubuntu 16.04 on my laptop and when I travel, I want to connect it to a Win7 laptop on my local network at home, using Remmina. I have successfully made the connection while both machines are on the same network but I'm trying to figure out how to set up connecting from outside my local network, which is using a Linksys EA6100 wifi router.

Comment: Ehm this is either a problem with your router or with your windows system. I assume you use your external IP+user+password with remmina? Cuz that's all you need on the client/Ubuntu side.  Start with "Linksys EA6100 wifi route", Invalid request should be logged by the router. Same for windows: if the router lets you in windows probably also logs request.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Ubuntu. You should probably try on https://superuser.com/